# How to use jQuery POST instead of html form to delete table entry

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to delete the table entry without opening the .php file using jQuery post.
The whole thing works without problems when I just use the usual html post form.

The alert(data) does not trigger, it only adds ".../?player_id_del=1" or whatever ID click into the URL.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is some of my index.php, i get the whole data from a database:

```
<table class = "table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Player_ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>First_Name</th>
                <th>Last_Name</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Colour</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <? foreach($playerArray as $player):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><? echo $player["PLAYER_ID"]; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $player["USERNAME"]; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $player["FIRST_NAME"]; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $player["LAST_NAME"]; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $player["RATING"]; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $player["COUNTRY"]; ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $player["COLOUR"]; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form id="del-form">
                            <div>
                                <input type="number" id="player_id_del" name="player_id_del" value="<?php echo  htmlspecialchars($player["PLAYER_ID"]); ?>" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <script>
                            $("#submit-btn").click(function(){
                                $.post("deletePlayer.php", $("#del-form").serialize() , function(data) {
                                    alert(data);
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <? endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here is my deletePlayer.php:

```
<?php
//include DatabaseHelper.php file
require_once('DatabaseHelper.php');

//instantiate DatabaseHelper class
$database = new DatabaseHelper();

//Grab variable id from POST request
$player_id = '';
if(isset($_POST['player_id_del'])){
    $player_id = $_POST['player_id_del'];
}

// Delete method
$error_code = $database->deletePlayer($player_id);


// Check result
if ($error_code == 1){
    echo "Player with ID: '{$player_id}' successfully deleted!'";
}
else{
    echo "Error can't delete Player with ID: '{$player_id}'. Errorcode: {$error_code}";
}
?>
```

Thank You in advance for any help!

Comment: You are posting without a given URL. Try adding this in the jQuery post function..

Comment: I don't understand exactly. I've used "deletePlayer.php" as the URL? What else could I use?

Comment: The the answer I have posted it's gonna work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues in your code 
E.g IDs for form and delete input button are repeating (id of element should not be same it should be unique),
The following code is the tested and working.

```js
<?php
//include DatabaseHelper.php file
require_once('DatabaseHelper.php');

//instantiate DatabaseHelper class
$database = new DatabaseHelper();
$response = array();
//Grab variable id from POST request
$player_id = '';
if(isset($_POST['player_id_del'])){
    $player_id = $_POST['player_id_del'];
}

// Delete method
$error_code = $database->deletePlayer($player_id);


// Check result
if ($error_code == 1){
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["id"] = $player_id;
    $response["message"] = "Player with ID: '{$player_id}' successfully deleted!'";
}
else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"]= "Error can't delete Player with ID: '{$player_id}'. Errorcode: {$error_code}";
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

```html
<table class = "table table-hover" id="mPlayersTabel">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Player_ID</th>
         <th>Username</th>
         <th>First_Name</th>
         <th>Last_Name</th>
         <th>Rating</th>
         <th>Country</th>
         <th>Colour</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <? foreach($playerArray as $player):?>
      <tr id= "<? echo $player["PLAYER_ID"]; ?>">
         <td><? echo $player["PLAYER_ID"]; ?></td>
         <td><? echo $player["USERNAME"]; ?></td>
         <td><? echo $player["FIRST_NAME"]; ?></td>
         <td><? echo $player["LAST_NAME"]; ?></td>
         <td><? echo $player["RATING"]; ?></td>
         <td><? echo $player["COUNTRY"]; ?></td>
         <td><? echo $player["COLOUR"]; ?></td>
         <td>
           
               <div>
                 <button type="submit" player-id="<? echo $player["PLAYER_ID"]; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</button>

               </div>
          
         </td>
      </tr>
      <? endforeach ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn-danger").on("click touchend" , function(){
                var id =  $(this).attr("player-id");
                 $.ajax({
                    url: 'deletePlayer.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        player_id_del: id
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                        //Add this line and try
                        response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                        alert(response['message']);
                        switch (response['success']) {
                            case 1:
                                $("#mPlayer" + response['id']).remove();
                                break;
                        }
        
                    }
            });
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I copied your code into my code. isset($_POST['player_id_del']) ==  true but the player_id is an empty string.

Comment: My Bad, we have used GET method so the value should be read as $_GET not $_POST

Comment: Thank You very much! I've tested it with $error_code = 1 / 0 and the alert always shows the correct ID for the specific button I clicked.

Comment: You are welcome! did you get what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

By default jQuery's click event reload the document so, you should try using,

```
$("#submit-btn").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Also instead of $.post, try using $.ajax

Comment: These two functions don't work when there is more than 1 entry in the table. Then the alert dialog only works for the first entry, but I cannot close it. After realoading the page it tries to download an .html file and breaks.